# Is there a way to prefill the username in the login screen of macos?

Tags: macos, login-screen

Is there a way to prefill the username when i turn on macos (i know about the security implication)?

Possibly without using the fast user switching option (system settings -> login options -> login window shows) but using command line to set it, if anyone knows how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two options, neither of which satisfy your criteria:

- Showing a list of users
- Showing a username and password field

It seems like you already know about this switch, but if you or anyone else wants to switch between these modes, navigate to the Lock Screen settings in System Settings and change "Login window shows" between "list of users" and "name and password."

Comment: Ah was hoping there was another way to set a default user and pre-fill the field so to only have to type the password - without using the "list of users" setting. Thanks for the info